# How to use properly sd Function

Tags: r

Is the sd function the biased or the unbiased standard deviation? If it is the unbiased one, what command would I have to use to get the biased one?

Comment: Check the manual page (`?sd`) in the "Details" section.

Comment: Multiply by (n-1)/n ?

Answer (score 1):

```
help(sd)
```

output: (sd and var use n-1)

```
Details
Like var this uses denominator n - 1.
```

To find population standard deviation: Even though `var` used `n-1` we can manipulate it to use `n` instead.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
n <- length(x)
sd_pop <- sqrt(var(x)*(n-1)/n)
sd_pop
```